# Phantom or real voltage determination

Tags: electrical

Can a 120 V/ 0.35 A input for a phone charger help to determine if voltage is real or phantom? I don't have a multimeter with impedance function. I have a problem circuit which shows to have 120V AC but when I plug in a 25 W light it will not light but there is now no power in line. However if I just plug in charger requiring 120v and .35 A, the phone shows to be charging. From this can I conclude that the voltage is real. Once I know that, then I can focus on where the current is being lost in this circuit. Thank you.

Comment: The voltage was real 120V but very very low current available due to a broken wire. Found break, fixed and all is well. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it will work IF the poor connection is not capable of passing 0.35A...

You don't get "phantom" readings of 120V, it's either 120V or it is not. But what you can get is a bad CONNECTION on a 120V circuit so that as soon as the load starts to pull any appreciable current, that connection increases in resistance and the voltage drops to where it can't even make your 25W lamp glow. 350mA is not a lot of current and it may end up not causing that voltage drop, so it will still "look" good, but it really is not.

Comment: I should have added, just use something more substantial, like a hair dryer or a small appliance. I like using radios because you can test circuit breakers with them when you are alone, but apparently few people have radios any more...

Comment: The charger isn't anywhere near 350ma.   That rating is due to freaky math relating to *power factor* in worst-case conditions.  It's easy for low voltage electronics to have very bad power factors that lead to very high "artificial" milliamp ratings.  That is useless for phantom-voltage-chasing purposes.   That thing may be more like 3.5 ma.

Comment: Circuit showing 116 V on multimeter will not power 25 W light or 1800 W hair dryer. It only powers phone charger. So, is this in fact real voltage and not phantom voltage?

Comment: You can also get induced voltage via magnetic/capacitive effects. But if a 25W bulb doesn't light up, it's not good.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't tell with electronic devices, because they don't act like simple resistors.   Plug in an old fashioned incandescent night light from the dollar store.  That will tell the tale.

Comment: LOL, my mother bought a bunch of night lights at the Dollar store once because she can't see well to walk around in the dark. I plugged them in for her and over half of them were DOA...